# How can I get notified when Android arrayadapter is being scrolled?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

As the Title already says, I have a list based on an arrayadapter and would like to get notified when the list is being scrolled (and only then, not when its being drawn).

How is this possible ?

Edit: My list looks like this:

```
public class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{

    public MyCustomAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId, ArrayList<String> processlist)
    {   
      .
      .
    }   

    @Override       
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {   
      .
      .
      .
    }
}
```

PS: Java/Android 2.3.4

Comment: In case of scroll..list getView() method is called..

Comment: yes, but its called for every item, and I would like it only to be called once for the scroll event and not the draw event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the desired you can have scroll listener on list as:

```
 setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // Some code that need to be applied simultaneous with scroll event
        }
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {
          // TODO Auto-generated method stub
          if(scrollState == 0) 
         // Scroll state 0 denotes scrolling is stopped.
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: The adapter that you are using might be used in any list.. So have shown you that sort of code..

Comment: Thanks, I think I got a few things confused in the list but I got it working.

Answer (score 0):

you can use setOnScrollListener()

source : [android_reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setOnScrollListener%28android.widget.AbsListView.OnScrollListener%29)

Comment: I'm new to this and don't really know how to use "setOnScrollListener()" with the ArrayAdapter that I am using. Could you please tell me how to do this ?